# ng-if with multiple conditions wont work

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, angular-ng-if

```
<tbody ng-repeat= "course in year.courses">
     <tr ng-repeat="theCourse in vm.courses" ng-if="theCourse._id==course && theCourse.term==('VT2'||'VT1')">
          <td >{{theCourse.courseName}}</td>
          <td >{{theCourse.courseCode}}</td>
          <td >{{theCourse.term}}</td>
          <td >{{theCourse.block}}</td>
          <td >{{theCourse.credits}}</td>

       </tr>
</tbody>
```

The `OR`-condition wont work, I have tried doing like the above, but also tried like this:

```
<tr ng-if="theCourse._id==course && theCourse.term=='VT2'||theCourse.term=='VT1'">
```

Somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `year.courses` and `vm.courses` are different?

Comment: may be use brackets `<tr ng-if="(theCourse._id==course && theCourse.term=='VT2')||theCourse.term=='VT1'">`

Comment: Thats on purpose since they are 2 different databases, year.courses stores the course in a specific year and vm.courses is all the courses, Thats why I have the first if-condition. The two first If-conditions work, the problem is that the last one after || do not. (´@WorkWe

Comment: Haha thanks! That solved it! @Mike0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<tr ng-if="theCourse._id === course && (theCourse.term === 'VT2'|| theCourse.term === 'VT1')">
```

Note: You should use `===` to compare values.

Comment: Thanks! The brackets solved the problem, but it still works with only two ==

Comment: This suggestion, because compare with `==` (just compare value), compare with `===` (compare value and type) :)

Answer (score 0):

may be use brackets

```
<tr ng-if="(theCourse._id==course && theCourse.term=='VT2')||theCourse.term=='VT1'">
```

i copied my comment, just to make it as an answer